# Is it possible to locate element by partial id match in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate elements with generated ids wherein some part of the ID is known; for example:

```
id="page_x002e_x0023_default-create-firstname"
```

in which the last 3 words (_default-create-firstname) are known but anything preceding that is subject to change.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can apply an [*ends-with* CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
By.cssSelector("[id$=default-create-firstname]")
```

**Update**

Some time went by since the answer was posted. Here some update from the linked mozilla developer page and comments below:

New use By.css instead of By.cssSelector

```
By.css("[id$=default-create-firstname]")
```

Also see the four possibilities of

- beginning with
- anywhere inside
- anywhere inside regardless capitalization
- end with

---

```
/* Internal links, beginning with "#" */
a[href^="#"] {
  background-color: gold;
}

/* Links with "example" anywhere in the URL */
a[href*="example"] {
  background-color: silver;
}

/* Links with "insensitive" anywhere in the URL,
   regardless of capitalization */
a[href*="insensitive" i] {
  color: cyan;
}

/* Links that end in ".org" */
a[href$=".org"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: and to match the start of an id you can: By.CssSelector("id^=default-create-firstname")

Comment: And to match elements with id that contain "partialId": By.cssSelector("[id*=partialId]")

Comment: None of these work for me. They all produce an InvalidSelectorException.

Comment: I know it is years later and Protractor may have changed, but this helped me. I'm wondering if @SteveStaple needed single quotes around the name. I had an input field whose ID looked like ADMIT_DATE followed by 4 unpredictable digits, and it is located with by.css('input[id^="ADMIT_DATE"]'),

Comment: 'By.cssSelector' has been changed to 'By.css'

Answer (score 36):

If you want to go down the xpath route then you could use `contains()`, like this:

```
//*[contains(@id,'_default-create-firstname')]
```

This will search the entire page for an id that contains the text "_default-create-firstname". It can be easily made more specific

Comment: This is a great technique. Might I ask where you found it? I don't see mention of it [on the documentation site I use](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Comment: @Cathal - I personally prefer this one as well.

Answer (score 21):

You can try out this in Java-Selenium: you can use either `ends-with()` or `contains()`. I think Both should work.

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ends-with(@id,'_default-create-firstname')]"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '_default-create-firstname')]"));
```

Comment: I have element with `ID=Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.New.NewRecord`

if I use following query - I successfully get the element
`FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.New.NewRecord']"))`

but if I try to get element by partial ID it fails
`FindElement(By.XPath("//*[ends-with(@id,'NewRecord')]"))`

What's wrong with the second query?

Answer (score 6):

This works with selenium vba

```
 .FindElementsByXPath( "//*[contains(@class, 'unique-string')]" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Work one

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id')]")
```

Not work ones, all got the same error, **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

```
1. driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[contains(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id')]")).text

2. driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[contains(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id')]").text).text

3. driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[contains(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id')]")).get_attribute("innerHTML")

4. driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[contains(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id')]").get_attribute("innerHTML")).get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

I use python 3.7.6, selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

I use: `a[id*='example']`

when my ID is something like **example_12**