# java-regex: How to write regular expression for two digit numbers

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver

I have password field with ID locator "j_idt90". However the ID is dynamic and the two digits in the preceeding changes everytime login page loads.

Iam using automation to capture this field and used below regular expression but it is failing. Do, let me know where I'm failing to identify the element.

Reg Exp - `driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt[0-9]{2}"));`

Comment: What if you use `".*j_idt[0-9]{2}.*"`? I doubt you can use a regex here at all.

Comment: I think that you can go around this by using an approach similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium). I do not think that the `findElement` supports regex search. I might be wrong though.

Comment: What is the signature of By.Id() ? Does that take a regular expression?

Comment: @GhostCat signature of By.Id() is it will  take any string.

Comment: @Aditya So what makes you think that you can then pass a regular expression which is evaluated as such in order to make a match?

Answer (score 3):

You can locate the element by XPath instead. Assuming that there is only one password field in your page, the following snippet should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
```

Comment: Using x-path you can also take advantage of functions such as "contains" or "starts-with". In this case it means you don't have to rely on the input type. My answer contains an example if you're curious.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, but it does show an alternative way to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

By.id does not take a regular expression, but a simple string as argument.

See here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Boni's answer, but you could try using the xpath function `starts-with`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'j_idt')]"));
```

This will search for any "input" elements which have an ID starting with the text 'j_idt'. See also http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp