# Find sum of all elements using ruby and selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

In my web page there are 5 values given in the text field(like $10, $20, $30, $40 and $50) and I am trying to sum the values using ruby and selenium WebDriver.

Here is my code:

```
def get_sum_of_all_elements()
    @logger.info("Searching element #{value1, value2, value3, value4, value5}");
    allelements = @driver.find_elements(:id = "lbl_val_")
    @logger.info("Total Elements Found with locator #{locator} are : #{allelements.size}");
    if allelements.start_with?("$")
        allelements = "((allelements))".tr('$', '')    #removing '$' sign from values
        iSum =0
        allelements.each do|i|
        iSum += i
        end
    end
end
```

I am expecting to see output as 150. Do I need to store values in an array?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for people to help with your question you'll need to provide some more details on the problem. e.g. exactly what isn't working in the way you expect, are you seeing an error message etc? Right now there seems to be a couple of problems with your code: the `value` variable is never assigned a value. Your `allelements.each` block is missing a closing `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of things you should modify in your code to make it work:

1. Fix how arguments are passed to `find_elements`; it should be `id: "lbl_val_"`.
2. `find_elements` returns an array of `WebDriver::Element` objects, so you must check the `value` for each object.
3. The string `"Searching element #{value1, value2, value3, value4, value5}"` is not valid since you are trying to interpolate the value of 5 variables chained with a comma. You either need to interplate only the variable (keeping commas as strings) or use square brackets (`[]`) to interpolate an array.

Now your code should look something like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
def get_sum_of_all_elements
  @logger.info("Searching element #{[value1, value2, value3, value4, value5]}")
  allelements = @driver.find_elements(id: "lbl_val_")
  @logger.info("Total Elements Found with locator #{locator} are : #{allelements.size}");

  if allelements.all? { |elem| elem.value.start_with?("$") }
    elements = allelements.map { |elem| elem.value.tr('$', '').to_i }
    elements.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

A few things to note:

- Parenthesis (`()`) were removed in method definition, ruby doesn't need them when no arguments are passed.
- There is no longer need to assign the final value to a variable (e.g `iSum`) since ruby will return the result of last evaluated code.
- If any value doesn't start with `"$"`, it will return `false`. You could change this by adding a default value after `if` block.
- Semicolons (`;`) were removed, you don't need them in ruby (unless you want to chain multiple statements in a singe line).

One more thing, the variables `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4`, `value5` and `locator` doesn't seem to be set anywhere in your method; you must set them within your method (or pass them as arguments) or you will get an error.

<sup>1</sup> *This considers the same logic that you seemed to be looking for in your code, that is, sum all values only if all of them start with `"$"`.*

Comment: Hi Gerry, Thanks for nice explanation and rectifying issues.

Comment: @Avnee Hope it helps get the result your are looking for (and please don't forget to click the tick -to accept the answer- if it does). :)

Comment: Would also like to know that how we can include partial ID in find_elements(id: "lbl_val_"). Web page contains ID's like "lbl_val_1", "lbl_val_2" for value1, value2, respectively.

Comment: Wow.. that's really cool. I am pretty new to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @Avnee I'm not sure, i haven't used it that much. But check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium), it might help you.

Comment: @Avnee Yes, SO is a great site, i recommend checking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what you are trying to do, but this might help. I assume you have an array of string values with dollar signs:

```
>> allelements = ["$10", "$20", "$30", "$40", "$50"]
=> ["$10", "$20", "$30", "$40", "$50"]
```

We can make a new array stripping out all non-numeric characters and transforming the string values to integers:

```
>> integers = allelements.map { |e| e.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i }
=> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Now use `inject` to sum the values:

```
>> integers.inject(:+)
=> 150
```