# Selecting elements by partial id using Protractor

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, protractor

In Selenium you can select an element by partial id using `'[id$=foobar]'`

But using protractor you do it `element(by.id(foobar))`

Is there anyway to get similar functionality using Protractor. I can't find in their documentation if you could do something like `element(by.id$(foobar))`.

Comment: post the code, Post the website!

Answer (score 5):

Referring to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium), I used this in one of my demo tests. You can do

```
element(by.css(["id$=ends_with_this"]));
```

Similarly for matching something that starts with abcd, you can do

```
element(by.css(["id^=abcd"]));
```

To see if the id contains abcd, you can do

```
element(by.css("[id*=partialId]"));
```

Moreover, you can even minimise your typing by using `$` for when using `css` selectors as

```
 $((["id^=abcd"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the XPath

```
//*[contains(@id,'foobar')]
```

with CSS

```
[id*='foobar']
```

Comment: isn't xpath slower than by id?

Comment: @MarkPytel XPath is slower and has less support than CSS selector. My order of locator preference is IDs, CSS selectors, and then if I'm trying to locate an element by contained text I use XPath (and I occasionally use LinkText/PartialLinkText).