# How to locate webelement by partial xpath in selenium webdriver (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on link using xpath. Xpath contains a number at the end which can vary. 
xpath is - **`//*[@id="cllink-Monday-OK-1"]`**

I can make a string using available variables which contains **"`cllink-Monday-OK-`** but number at the end of `xpath` is dynamic and it's unknown.

How to locate this link by `find_element_by_xpath`.

Comment: try - //*[@id*="cllink-Monday-OK"]

Comment: @Ranjith's Thanks for response.. But it didn't work . 
It says The string '//*[@id*="cllink-Monday-OK-]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: try with css selctor!!

Comment: @Ranjith's that's not a valid XPath. If you have an answer, post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to locate element by partial id match in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium)

Comment: Use id , why you are using xpath

Comment: Lets try this `//[starts-with(@id, 'cllink-Monday-OK')]`

Answer (score 4):

Use this xpath

```
  //*[contains(@id, 'cllink-Monday-OK-')]
```