# Selenium: How to Click a Variable Button

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

```
<a id="btn_yyyy_69" href="javascript:void(0);"
 onclick="checkOnline(this,'69','UCnHasdadhrz3mTd1A7t5TQ','yyyy');"
 class="gbut_red">Yepsribe</a>
```

and xpath like `//*[@id="btn_yyyy_69"]`  -- 69,It's constantly changing.

i tried like this ;

```
WebDriverWait waitc = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
waitc.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='btn_yyyy_")));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btn_yyyy_")).Click();
```

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium

Comment: if the id is constantly changing then select an attribute that is not or the text if there's no other choice.

Comment: drutubeview.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id$=btn_ysub]")).Click(); dont work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match link by partial `@id` value, you can try

```
By.XPath("//a[starts-with(@id, 'btn_yyyy_')]")
By.CssSelector("a[id^='btn_yyyy_']")
```

Also you can locate link by its text:

```
By.LinkText("Yepsribe")
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only button with an id with btn_yyyy in it, use:

```
//a[contains(@id, 'btn_yyyy')]
```

That should work only if this is the only button which has an id with that notation in it.

If there are multiple buttons with partial id btn_yyyy and this is the only butotn with text Yepsribe, try:

```
//a[contains(@id, 'myclass') and text() = 'Yepsribe']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
//a[text()='Yepsribe']
```

Is the best way to look for elements with dynamic id.
It also prevent you from code changes (ex. all button classes or id have changed to another template).