# Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using ChromeDriver of Selenium with Python and I'm trying to find a button on my page that has the following HTML:

```
<input id="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id255:new" type="submit" name="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id255:new" value="New" class="kbutton-white">
```

The only thing I know being constant is the id and name ending with "new" and I'm trying to use the following code to identify and click that element:

```
test_runner.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*=new]').click()
```

However, I get this error when I run the code:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id*=new]"}
```

What's my mistake here?

Update: This element was inside an iframe and I had to switch to the iframe before trying to find the element. Please see comments for the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to locate element by partial id match in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium)

Comment: I'm following http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html for locating elements with Python and not sure if I can use the suggested solution there?

Comment: Make sure the element is present on the page when you run that statement and its ID is the value you've mentioned. Is possible that the `<input>` is added dynamically or its ID is changed.

Comment: 1- I tried with ("[id$=new]") as suggested in the accepted answer on the other question and got the same error.
2- @Titus I can confirm that the id  and name are there as I mentioned above. However, I know that <input> is added dynamically. How does it change thigs?

Comment: The css selector was find, I'm not sure what library you're using but it needs to have some kind of function for waiting until an element is present on the page. Something like `driver.wait(until.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*=new]'), 1000)`

Comment: I'm using Python and tried time.sleep(5) to run the method after 5 seconds and I know the element is present then but still have the same issue.

Comment: @Jorjani , Check whether input node located inside an iframe

Comment: @Andersson Hah! It is inside an iframe!

Comment: @Jorjani , then you need to [switch to iframe](https://computerrecipes.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/selenium-webdriver-interact-with-an-element-inside-an-iframe/) to handle elements inside

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have shared to invoke `click()` on the desired element you can use the following `css_selector` :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.kbutton-white[id$='new'][name$='new'][value='New']").click()
```

Explaination :

- `.kbutton-white` : The *class* attribute.
- `id$='new'` : *id* attribute ends with **new**
- `name$='new'` : *name* attribute ends with **new**
- `value='New'` : The *value* attribute.

But it seems the element is dynamic so you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.kbutton-white[id$='new'][name$='new'][value='New']"))).click()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893747/java-selenium-webdriver-expression-finding-dynamic-element-by-ccs-that-starts-wi/65893830#65893830)
- [How to click a dynamic link with in a drupal 8 website using xpath/css selector while automating through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777770/how-to-click-a-dynamic-link-with-in-a-drupal-8-website-using-xpath-css-selector/59778115#59778115)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)