# How to click a dynamic link with in a drupal 8 website using xpath/css selector while automating through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on an edit tab link, and its in the form of a hyperlink in an unordered list.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li><a href="/node/2658/edit" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/2658/edit">Edit</a></li>
```

I have been trying to use `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Edit')` to find the element, however always get a `NoSuchElementException`.

I have also used the by partial text fxn, with all variations of the html, and receive the same error.

There is also the following html I found that includes the proper link:

```
<link rel="edit-form" href="/node/2658/edit" />
```

Is there a selenium function I can use to go to this edit page?

Comment: @KunduK Could you expand on that? Not familiar with what you're talking about

Comment: I wish I could, however it requires being logged into the dev mode of our website, so unfortunately I can't share that info...

Comment: No worries.If you inspect your element the EDIT element just traverse upwards in the DOM tree and check if there any tag `<iframe>` if there you need to switch to that iframe in oder to access.

Comment: Viewing the entire page source, there are no instances of <iframe> anywhere .    Well... there are a couple, but none none in any relevant sections and they're always closed in the same line

Comment: Well the iframe tag always be start and close. However Check the answer posted by @DebanjanB Hope this will help to your resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you shared the *value* of `href` and `data-drupal-link-system-path` attributes clearly seems to be dynamic due to the presence of the value **`2658`**. So you need to construct a dynamic locator to locate the element.

As  the desired element is a dynamic element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li>a[href$='edit'][data-drupal-link-system-path^='node']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a[contains(@href, 'edit') and starts-with(@data-drupal-link-system-path, 'node')][text()='Edit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Explanation of the dynamic CSS_SELECTOR

To consider only the static part of `href` and `data-drupal-link-system-path` attributes you can use the following wildcards in [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

- **$** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*
- **^** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*

So the most granular css_selector would be :

```
li>a[href$='edit'][data-drupal-link-system-path^='node']
```

---

### Explanation of the dynamic XPATH

To consider only the static part of `href` and `data-drupal-link-system-path` attributes you can use the following functions of [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

- `contains()` : To indicate an attribute value *contains*
- `starts-with()` : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*

So the most granular xpath would be :

```
//li/a[contains(@href, 'edit') and starts-with(@data-drupal-link-system-path, 'node')][text()='Edit']
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python/59637443#59637443)
- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893747/java-selenium-webdriver-expression-finding-dynamic-element-by-ccs-that-starts-wi/65893830#65893830)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)
- [Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298553/finding-elements-by-css-selector-with-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/50299190#50299190)

---

### tl; dr

You can find a detailed discussion on **NoSuchElementException** in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. The CSS option worked perfectly. Could you explain how you came to that conclusion so quickly, I'd like to understand on a deeper level

Comment: @MichaelLively Updated the answer with all the relevant details and references for your deeper level understanding. Let me know if you have further queries.