# Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium4

I have the below HTML element that I need to find. Now, this "id" name is dynamic in the way that the  int "0" at the end will change, but I know what it will be. The first int in "0-0" will also change, but it doesn't matter what it will be.

```
<div id="ui-select-choices-row-0-0">
```

I've tried the below code that looks for an element that starts with "#ui-select-choices-row-" and ends with the desired input of "int", but it's not finding it as expected. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Attempt 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='#ui-select-choices-row-'] and div[id$='"+int+" div']"));
```

Attempt 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='ui-select-choices-row-'] and div[id$='"+int+"']"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close enough. You need to remove the **`#`** from the beginning of the `id` as **`#`** itself denotes the `id` attribute.

---

### Explanation of the dynamic CSS_SELECTOR

To consider only the static part of `href` and `data-drupal-link-system-path` attributes you can use the following wildcards in [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

- **$** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*
- **^** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*

So the most granular css_selector would be :

```
div[id^='ui-select-choices-row-'][id$='" +count+ "']
```

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='ui-select-choices-row-'][id$='" +count+ "']"));
```

**Note**: `int` is a keyword, use other names as the variable name.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298553/finding-elements-by-css-selector-with-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/50299190#50299190)
- [How to click a dynamic link with in a drupal 8 website using xpath/css selector while automating through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777770/how-to-click-a-dynamic-link-with-in-a-drupal-8-website-using-xpath-css-selector/59778115#59778115)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I had a different variable name, but I had mentioned it as "int" to make sure it was understood that it was a number I was referring to.