# How to fix TimeOutException error when using explicit wait in selenium using java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

```
try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
        } catch (TimeOutException toe) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`TimeOutException` exception is thrown when Selenium fails locating on the page element matching the passed locator. `myDynamicElement` id in your case.
This may be caused by one of the following:
1)
You are using a wrong locator.
2)
The element is inside an iframe.
3)
You have opened a new tab / window on your browser but did not switch the driver to the new opened tab.
Etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Java Exceptions

When executing Java programs different errors can occur, e.g. coding errors made by the programmer, errors due to wrong input or any other unforeseeable things. When any of these error occurs, Java will throw an exception.

---

### Java Try-Catch{}

The try and catch keywords come in pairs.

- *try*: The *try* statement allows you to define a block of code to be tested for errors while it is being executed.
- *catch*: The *catch* statement allows you to define a block of code to be executed, if an error occurs in the try block.

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated()

[visibilityOfElementLocated()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0 which returns the WebElement once it is located and visible else raises [***TimeOutException***](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html).

---

### This usecase

I don't see any such syntactical error in your code block:

```
try {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
} catch (TimeOutException toe) {
  System.out.println("WebElement wasn't found");
}
```

However there can be numerous reasons for the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) not being found and some of them are as follows:

- The [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447) you have adopted doesn't identifies any element in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- The [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) you have adopted is unable to identify the element as it is not within the browser's [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- The [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637443/7429447) you have adopted identifies the element but is invisible due to presence of the attribute **style="display: none;"**.
- The [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893830/7429447) you have adopted doesn't **uniquely** identifies the desired element in the *HTML DOM* and currently finds some other *hidden* / *invisible* element.
- The *WebElement* you are trying to locate is within an `<iframe>` tag.
- The *WebDriver* instance is looking out for the *WebElement* even before the element is present/visibile within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Solution

Each of the above mentioned cases can be addressed using different approaches. You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472940/7429447)
- [Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212233/7429447)