# Does selenium IDE have a way to handle dynamic elements?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, ui-automation, selenium-ide

I was using selenium IDE to automate testing on a web page that has dynamic xpath in it.
I noticed selenium IDE was capturing the xpath fine the first time playing it. Then after closing the browser and opening, of course the xpath has changed, but the target saved was the old xpath.

Is there a way to handle this in selenium?

I know I can use the `.contains` method but can i apply that to the target?
[Picture of selenium IDE firefox extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEv1w.png)

Answer (score 2):

To identify the dynamic elements you can construct [*dynamic locators*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637443/7429447). As couple of examples:

- Using a *css* for a `<span>` tag with *`id`* attribute starting with `abc`:

  ```
  span[id^='abc']
  ```
- Using a *css* for a `<span>` tag with *`class`* attribute containing `pqr`:

  ```
  span[class*='pqr']
  ```
- Using a *xpath* for a `<span>` tag with *`value`* attribute ending with `xyz`:

  ```
  span[value$='xyz']
  ```
- Using a *xpath* for a `<span>` tag with *`id`* attribute starting with `abc`:

  ```
  //span[starts-with(@id, 'abc')]
  ```
- Using a *xpath* for a `<span>` tag with *`class`* attribute containing `pqr`:

  ```
  //span[contains(@class, 'pqr')]
  ```

---

### Explanation of the dynamic CSS_SELECTOR

The wildcards are defined as follows:

- **`^`** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*
- **`*`** : To indicate an attribute value *contains*
- **`$`** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893830/7429447)