# How do I click Selenium "onclick"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, onclick

I want to click on "**cmd('abcdef:perxform',{'id':'5'},true)**".

```
html code --->    <div class="abcdef_button_small" onclick="if (!check_health(1,3)) return; if (!check_timers(1,$(this))) return; $('#dialog_abcdefs .disabled_controls').show(); cmd('abcdef:perxform',{'id':'5'},true); ">AAAA</div>
```

```
xpath code --->    //*[@id="abcdef_5"]/div[4]
```

```
xpath code --->    /html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[22]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[5]/div[4]
```

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@onclick='('abcdef:perxform',{'id':'5'},true);']" ))).click()
```

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@onclick=('abcdef:perxform',{'id':'5'},true); ]").click()
```

the above didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *`onclick`* attribute with [dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713359/7429447) to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[onclick*='show'][onclick*='perxform'][onclick*='5']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@onclick, 'show') and contains(@onclick, 'perxform')][contains(@onclick, '5')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893830/7429447)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587006/7429447)

---

### *Proof of concept*

Not sure if the HTML was tailored as `<div>` tags are seldom clickable. However here is poc:

[image: poc]

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.
i want to click "perxform',{'id':'5'}".
There are values with too many IDs.

Comment: It didn't work again :/

Comment: driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@onclick=\"if (!check_health(2,3)) return; if (!check_timers(1,$(this))) return; $('#dialog_abcdefs .disabled_controls').show(); cmd('abcdef:perform',{'id':'3'}, true); \"]").click()

I tried with "katalon". recorder gave this code and it worked in "katalon".

but when I tried this code "vs code" it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the preface of the answer where I mentioned about _dynamic values_ and _`WebDriverWait`_? Probhably you are messing up things. Just copy paste the code and retest and let me know the status.

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@onclick, 'show') and contains(@onclick, 'abcdef:perxform')][contains(@onclick, '5')]"))).click()

clicked with this code.

I just need to open the "dropdown menu" it is in for it to work.
Does it work without clicking the "dropdown menu"?

Comment: @Berk You never mentioned about any dropdown in your question. It was only evident you were invoking `click()`. Hence the answer. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Comment: @Berk _clicked with this code_: Glad to be able to help you.