# How to construct locators for dynamic elements using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I am working on web scraping from LinkedIn. I have a filter for roles on a sales navigator page. Here I need to add filter  for roles using python.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//[@id='ember219']/div/input").send_keys('Marketing')
```

However, the xpath keeps changing each time I open the page like this:

```
//[@id='ember220']/div/input
//[@id='ember221']/div/input
//[@id='ember222']/div/input
```

Please help me match the pattern for my driver so that each time I have a smooth action happening. Roles can be Marketing , VP, Director so on.

Comment: "//*[contains(@id, 'ember')]"

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the desired element in the form of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *id* attribute values like *`ember220`*, *`ember221`* are dynamically generated by [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators as it is.

---

### Solution

As the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) keeps on changing you can construct [*Dynamic Locator Strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637443/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and `starts-with(@id, 'static_id_part')`:

  ```
  //*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')]/div/input
  ```

  Effectively:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')]/div/input").send_keys('Marketing')
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `contains(@id, 'static_id_part')`:

  ```
  //*[contains(@id, 'ember')]/div/input
  ```

  Effectively:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@id, 'ember')]/div/input").send_keys('Marketing')
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and starts-with(`^`):

  ```
  [id^='ember'] > div > input
  ```

  Effectively:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='ember'] > div > input").send_keys('Marketing')
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and contains(`*`):

  ```
  [id*='ember'] > div > input
  ```

  Effectively:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id*='ember'] > div > input").send_keys('Marketing')
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Does selenium IDE have a way to handle dynamic elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713359/7429447)
- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893830/7429447)
- [Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299190/7429447)