# Selenium C# - Find element by Id dynamically (Id name unknown)

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I'm trying to find an element where the Id name has changed (and I'm not sure what it's been changed to), so I need to find it dynamically instead. The current code is:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "address.surname")]
public IWebElement AddressLastname_Input { get; set; }

public void AddressEnter_function(IWebDriver D, DataRow UserDetail)
 {
   log.sendkeylog(AddressLastname_Input, 
   UserDetail["LastName"].ToString(), 
   "Enter LastName Address Section", drv: D);
 }
```

The corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label " for="address.surname">
        Last name<span>&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font></span>
   </label>         
    <input id="address.surname" name="lastName" class="form-control form- 
    control" required="required" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

The error I get is "Cannot find element by Id". Is there a way of finding it without knowing the specific Id name/text?

Comment: provide some html sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to locate element by partial id match in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium)

Comment: The ID is right there... what's the question? I'm confused. If ID keeps changing, that element also has a `name` attribute... have you tried that?

Comment: JeffC that is exactly what I posted in my answer. Glad I was not the only one that was confused by this. I also added two different xpaths to try. Funny how I was downgraded for my answer though lol.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer without seeing your HTML markup, but if Id and name keep changing, perhaps you can try locating it via CSS or even better, XPath?

XPath has proven to be more reliable for me albeit a bit slower.

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='login']")).Click();
```

In your code, form-control class should give you a hint so maybe you want to run an xpath that searches for elements of type input, that have the class form-control and optionally checking value as well?

Comment: `FindElement` doesn't have overload with `int` parameter.

Comment: *XPath has proven to be more reliable* You base that statement on what? `xpath` is not more or less reliable than any other locator strategy

Comment: @Guy  where the structure of a website is known and stays the same, xpath can be used. XPath has many different selectors allowing to use OR operands as well.

Comment: `xpath` can be used on dynamic page as well. There are only only two functionalities `xpath` has but `cssSelector` doesn't have: going to parent and locating by text (actually `cssSelector` *can* locate by text but it isn't supported by selenium).

Answer (score -1):

This request is not making sense to me 100%. If the element is not found, is it on an iFrame or modal by chance?

Is the id changing? If so you could try:

```
    //div[@class='form-group']/input[@name='lastName']
     or
    //label[@for='address.surname']/following-sibling::input
```

Comment: whomever is downgrading answers, you may want to reply as to why. Hate when people come through and shit on a thread in stealth mode. Explain why it is not helpful and what your solution is. You have a new contributor OP here that is not used to writing a detailed explanation and two people have tried to help.