# how to find element using xpath selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, htmlelements

Here is my html of my element which i am able to find

```
<span data-bind="text: myAge()" xpath="1">Showing 1 of 25 people</span>
```

i could find above element using code like

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@data-bind='text: myAge()']")]
```

I have another element in Html like which get dynamic ids

```
<input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: code, attr: { id: 'myTable_code_' + $index() }" type="text" id="myTable_code_0" >
```

i tried to find same as above

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@data-bind='textInput: code']")]
```

But i get error that "It is not able to find element"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data-bind` attribute is `"textInput: code, attr: { id: 'myTable_code_' + $index() }"`, you need to use all of it

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@data-bind='textInput: code, attr: { id: 'myTable_code_' + $index() }']")]
```

Or partial attribute

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[contains(@data-bind, 'textInput: code')]")]
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Can you give me some helpful link to learn this?

Comment: @James which part are you referring to? I don't know any official docs for anything in my answer, this is just from experience.

Comment: The one you used to find using contains

Comment: @James I just searched in google, something like "selenium find element by partial attribute", for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium

Comment: There are some good docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath). I prefer CSS selectors and you can find docs on the [w3c site](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview).

Comment: @James here you are - http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf :)