# How can I distinguish between the same class for LinkedIn's job search text box and job location search text box

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, linkedin-api

**Context**

I am currently trying to use Helium/Selenium to bulk search for and scrape jobs on Linkedin. I am finding elements to click on using the class. However, as you can see from the below I the search box for both the jobs and location have the same class.

```
Search box for jobs class="jobs-search-box__text-input"
Search box for location class="jobs-search-box__text-input"
```

A picture below shows this also:

[image: Class for location]

[image: Class for jobs]

So when I run the below code (Helium, though the same thing happened for Selenium) it typed the text into the job textbox. I also tried running the class in the second input in the above text but it showed up as an error.

```
write('Trainee Developer', into=S(".jobs-search-box__text-input"))
write('London', into=S(".jobs-search-box__text-input"))
```

**Problem**

Is there any way I can distinguish between these two classes for the different search boxes for Selenium?

Comment: Since those elements have unique `ID`s, you can [select by ID](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id).

Comment: I thought about this, but the website uses ember which changes every time. So even if I use the id, the moment I perform another action like go on a different page or come back to it after I search for a different job/location, it changes and what I saved does not work.. Any work around?

Comment: Fair point, but I imagine the `ID` is following a standard format, right? If its just the number changing at the end, then you can use CSS selectors instead - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium), but you'd use the prefix match `^=` instead of suffix match as in that example.

Comment: NICE! This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can generate xpaths of both element and use it for finding them.
like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")).sendKeys("test1");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath2")).sendKeys("test2");
```

You can get `xpath` easily from chrome: Inspect element >> right click highlighted code >> and then click copy xpath .

Comment: Thanks for this, but the issue is that the xpath keeps changing because of the ember class. So even if I use the xpath, it changes and won't work the next time I use it.

Comment: I understand .
You can try this :[@class=’ jobs-search-box__text-input’]/child::input[1] and [@class=’ jobs-search-box__text-input’]/child::input[2].

Comment: I think it will solve your problem.
for more information you can use this -- https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this. Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Though I have found a fix already. But thanks a lot for the contribution! Really appreciate your time and effort.