# Selenium to check if a website displays cookie consent popup

Tags: python, selenium

I am building a dynamic scraper with selenium and flask that can take in any URL and scrape for cookies and other details. Now I want to check if the URL has any cookie consent popup. I am unable to make this feature dynamic.

I have tried PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, it works only for some website

```
url="https://www.spitzer-silo.com/"
 
desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

driver.get(url)

myDiv = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Cookie')
```

https://www.spitzer-silo.com/ works
https://www.siemens.com/de/de.html doesn't work

Also, I am searching with the "Cookie" keyword, which may not be present on some websites

another approach, I tried using a window handle but it shows only one window

```
url="https://www.siemens.com/de/de.html"

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}

# Create the webdriver object and pass the arguments
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Chrome will start in Headless mode
options.add_argument('headless')

# Ignores any certificate errors if there is any
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

# Startup the chrome webdriver with executable path and
# pass the chrome options and desired capabilities as
# parameters.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

# Send a request to the website and let it load
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)

whandle = driver.window_handles
```

['CDwindow-E9E6A9B1021BBA75132EF9DCA40A2824']

Is there any way I could check if there is a popup on the website and then check if the popup has a text cookie on it

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: You might try searching by partial ID text. In your example page the cookie popup has 'cookie' in the div ID. That might work for more websites too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248804/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium

Comment: You can also check the length of the driver.window_handles list. If it's greater than 1 you can switch to the 2nd one and look for cookie related elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will look into the partial ID search. As for the driver.window_handles, I am only getting one window as a result for the website that has a cookie popup, I also tried using sleep for elements to load, but it is the same result

Comment: What website generates a popup that doesn't show up on window_handles?

Comment: https://www.siemens.com/de/de.html , I have include the code part in the question. Also in this website there is a popup with text "Cookie" button, but the partial link text give error ( no such elements )

Comment: That isn't a new window, it's just an HTML element. It has some text that says "cookies", maybe you can just find element by text (not link text)

Comment: on this website https://www.siemens.com/de/de.html, I tried scraping all the buttons using ```driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button")``` but it is not getting the button ```<button role="button" data-testid="uc-deny-all-button" class="sc-eDvSVe cTBEww" style="margin: 0px 6px;">Cookies ablehnen</button>```